# "Closed" curve and constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a function $H(x,y)$, which is continuously differentiable. I also know its closed-formed expression. I want to prove that the the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $H(x,y) = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a constant, is a "closed" curve, not in the topological meaning, but in the way that it makes a loop (imagine a circle of radius 1). I also know that $H$ achieves a minimum at $(x*,y*)$. Can I use this fact to show that the curves are "closed", around $(x*,y*)$ (is there a general theorem showing this?) or do i have to prove the injectivity with my special case (I've done that, but it is not that elegant)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For a function $H:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, it is in general not true that 
$$
H^{-1}(\alpha) = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2~:~H(x,y)=\alpha\}
$$
is a closed curve in the sense of the unit circle.  In fact, it may not even be a curve at all.  For instance, if you let
$$
u(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
e^{-1/(1-t^2})&if& |t|<1 \\
0 & if & |t|\geq 1\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
and then let
$$
H(x,y) = u(x)u(y),~ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2
$$
then $H$ is differentiable and
$$
H^{-1}(0) = \{(x,y)~:~ |x|\geq 0~or~ |y|\geq 0\}
$$
which is clearly not a curve, in the sense that the closed unit circle is a curve.

One tool which can be used to show that $H^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a curve is the Implicit Function Theorem:  You must check that
$$
\nabla H(x,y)\neq \bar 0~\mbox{whenever}~ H(x,y)=\alpha.
$$
It still does not follow that, in such a case, the curve is closed, even if the function $H$ has a global minimum, achieved at a single point $(x^*,y^*)$.  Think of the part of a paraboloid with a half-cylinder "glued smoothly" to it.

I don't know of a general theorem which can be applied, and without knowing more about the specific function you are dealing with, it is difficult to come up with a useful strategy.

EDIT: One thing that comes to mind is to show that the restriction of $H$ to any line through $(x^*,y^*)$ is concave up.  Then, along each ray with origin $(x^*,y^*)$, $H$ takes on the value $\alpha$ exactly once.  For $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$, let $R_\theta$ be the ray given by
$$
(x,y) = (x^*,y^*)+t(\cos \theta,\sin\theta),~t\geq 0.
$$
Denote by $\bar r(\theta)$ the point on $R_\theta$ where $H$ takes the value $\alpha$.  Then $\bar r :[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous, $\bar r([0,2\pi])=H^{-1}(\alpha)$ and $\bar r(0)=\bar r(2\pi)$ so that $H^{-1}(\alpha)$ is a closed curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have assumed $H$ continuously differentiable. If $H$ is $C^\infty$ (I guess this can be weakened), has a critical point at $(0,0)$, and  the Hessian has nonzero determinant there then this critical point is called *nondegenerate*. If in such a  case the Hessian is positive definite then we have a strict local minimum at $(0,0)$. Furthermore the [Morse Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma) guarantees the following: We can introduce new coordinates $(\xi,\eta)$ in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ such that in these coordinates $H$ assumes the form $$\hat H(\xi,\eta)=\xi^2+\eta^2\ .$$
In terms of these coordinates it is  obvious that the level lines of $H$ are closed curves.